# Does Google Cloud Run support streaming response data?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I just deployed my application to Google Cloud Run. It has an HTTP end-point that returns a streaming response, so the client can start rendering data as it comes in instead of waiting for the response to complete (which takes ~ 10 seconds).

The response has a content-type header `application/stream+json`, and the data is written to the response as separate lines. I have had this app deployed elsewhere over HTTPS and the streaming worked just fine there.

However, when deployed on Google Cloud Run the client doesn't receive any data until the response has completed.

Is this a limitation of Google Cloud Run, or is there a way I can fix this?

Comment: There is a proxy (GFE) in front of Cloud Run. Your client is connecting to the proxy and not directly to your application. Once your service has returned a request to the proxy, the proxy returns a request to the client. At this time (which might change) streaming is not supported.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For "managed" Cloud Run, no. From https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/issues:

> Cloud Run (fully managed) currently does not support HTTP streaming.

However Cloud Run on GKE does support streaming response data.

Comment: Cloud Run on GKE does not support gRPC streaming, though.

Comment: @guillaume-blaquiere Tried that, and confirmed: Cloud Run does support streaming response data when run on top of GKE (instead of the fully managed version).

Comment: @RobvanMaris Thanks! I've updated the answer accordingly, please accept if it answers your question.

Comment: This answer should be updated, as of 6 days ago, cloud run supports all manner of streamed responses, including gRPC

Answer (score 3):

It will from Oct 2020

Cloud Run now supports server-side streaming:

https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/serverless/cloud-run-now-supports-http-grpc-server-streaming

With this addition, Cloud Run can now:

- Send responses larger than the previous 32 MB limit.
- Run gRPC services with server-streaming RPCs and send partial responses in a single request—in addition to existing support for unary (non-streaming) RPCs.
- Respond with server-sent events (SSE), which you can consume from your frontend using the HTML5 EventSource API.